# Example of a semi-orthogonal matrix with a condition on the norm of its rows

Tags: matrices, orthonormal

Let $m>n$. I would like to find an example of a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ such that the columns of $M$ are orthonormal vectors (for the euclidean norm), and such that the maximal euclidean norm of the row vectors of $M$ are of order $\sqrt{n/m}$. Is there a simple way to do this ?

Comment: If some norms of the rows of $M$ are unequal, pick two rows $i$ and $j$ such that $\|m_{i\ast}\|>\sqrt{n/m}>\|m_{j\ast}\|$. Apply a [Givens rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation) matrix in the $(i,j)$-th plane for some appropriate angle $\theta$ to make $\|m_{j\ast}\|=\sqrt{n/m}$. (This is equivalent to solving a quadratic equation in $\tan\theta$.) Repeat the same procedure until all rows have the same norm. This recursive algorithm will end in at most $m-1$ iterations.